# notifyDataSetChanged not updating ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I've read all the posts about this issue but I still can't get my ListView to update.
I am extending ListActivity.
Here's my ArrayAdapter:

```
 public List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();    
 public ArrayAdapter<String> allsongs;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    allsongs = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.song_items, songs);

 BindAllSongs();        
 ListView listView=getListView();
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
 }
```

now, when I delete a file I want the ListView to update:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_file:
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/AudioStreamRecorder/" + getListView().getAdapter().getItem(info.position).toString());
            file.delete();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    allsongs.notifyDataSetChanged();    
                }
            });

            return true;
        case R.id.cancel:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In my BindAllSongs(); method:

```
public void BindAllSongs() {
 ...
 ...
setListAdapter(allsongs);
    }
```

This works great (the files are being deleted from sd card) but the list never updates. When I navigate away, then return to the ListView, the item is gone.  (Returning to the ListView calls BindAllSongs(); again.)
Thank you for any help, if you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in the ArrayAdapter are not actually tied to the file system. You need to call remove on the item(s) that gets deleted and THEN you can call notifyDataSetChanged (although you may not need to).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: you call `((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).remove(item)`. you can get the item with `getListAdapter().getItem(position)`. you could also override the adapter's remove method and have that method delete the file and remove the item from the list.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and report back.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble here. Since I am deleting the file from the boolean onContextItemSelected there is no value for `position`. I tried setting up `protected void onListItemLongClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  item = getListAdapter().getItem(position)
  
 }` but that didn't help. I'm really lost here...

Comment: OK it looks like it's working...I did `Object item2 = getListView().getAdapter().getItem(info.position);
          ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).remove(item2);
             file.delete();` But I still have a question.  The line `((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).remove(item2);` is giving a warning `Type safety: The method remove(Object) belongs to the raw type ArrayAdapter. References to generic type ArrayAdapter<T> should be parameterized` Although it's still working.  Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand how it's working since my ArrayAdapter is not called directly in this block.

Comment: the adapter has a type associated with it right? it's ArrayAdapter<String> but you are passing an instance of Object into it. the warning should go away if you pass in a String. also, you should be able to get the adapter by calling `getListAdapter()` instead of `getListView().getAdapter()`